# Etherscan "Write Contract" Tab - what is it for?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether, erc-20

What is the purpose of the `Write Contract` Tab in Etherscan?

For example, if you look up the `QTUM` Token Contract on Etherscan (https://bit.ly/2IsddkT) and then tap on the `Write Contract` TAB, you have before you all of that contract's Functions:

-`approve`

-`transferFrom()`

-`transfer`

etc.

And I mean they're not just simply listed there, you can actually *interact* with them, input values into them, etc.

Why?

Are you actually able to execute *all* of these functions? Meaning, perform the transferring of Tokens from some person's account to *your* account for example?

I assume - and hope - the answer for this is "no", but am I right or wrong about that?

Cause it certainly seems its about to let you do this: 
-it lets you connect your account to that contract via `MetaMask`, 
-it then lets you set values - like how many Tokens you want to transfer to your own account, etc.

I mean I haven't actually pulled the trigger on executing any of the available functions (I don't wanna risk throwing away `ETHER` or "experimentation") - but its certainly didn't look like it was going to stop me from doing so.

So, what's going on here? What's the point of having this Tab, and this ability to "write" to the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, but there's more.

Those are writable functions in the smart contract. This is the interface a "wallet" communicates with.

If you're not a developer, then this might seem a little abstract. Smart contracts expose functions that accept inputs and return results. In between, they can manipulate the contract's internal storage, called "state", calculate things, check things, or call upon functions in other contracts. It's a versatile language.

Normally, those functions are utilized by a user interface (UI) or a server that reads/writes the contract. In other words, it's more of a developer's interface than a user interface. However, contract security design *always* proceeds on the assumption that the user (or attacker) may communicate with the raw interface. One way to do so is the method you have discovered.

> Are you actually able to execute all of these functions?

You can try.

Whether you succeed or not depends on how the contract is written. You will have to sign a transaction, and the contract will know who signed (called `msg.sender` in the code). It shouldn't let you `transfer` or `approve` funds you don't have.

For emphasis, security and what or isn't allowed is always a contract-level concern because a hostile user will simply not use the given UI if the UI is the only thing stopping bad behavior.

Following common sense and a common understanding of what a token should do, checking the sender's balance is probably a first step for such a contract.

At line 66 in the contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0x9a642d6b3368ddc662CA244bAdf32cDA716005BC#code

```
if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
```

For the transfer to proceed, the sender's balance must be at least as much as the amount to transfer and the amount to transfer must be more than zero. So, if you have enough tokens, it will work.

Hope it helps.

Comment: OK, a couple of things: I am a Developer, and so I do get the "abstract" stuff - but I'm still not clear on WHY the "Write Contract" Tab is being made available to us in the first place - which was my main question. It sounds like what you're saying is that hackers usually try to "attack" a Smart Contract by altogether skipping its UI/Front-End (typically a Website) and engaging directly with its "public" functions. OK, if that is indeed what you're saying, how is that related to why "Write Contract" is made available to us? What's the point of having it? So we can test vulnerabilities?

Comment: The situation is analogous to API endpoints. If contracts are going to have ABI, which they do, then it could be used for good or for evil because everyone will have access. Syncing the chain and using a CLI style or using a general-purpose GUI is a matter of convenience. It doesn't change the security guarantees coded in the contract. If you mean "Why make it convenient?" it roughly answers itself, no?

Comment: Well, to answer your question: no, I did not ask "Why make it convenient?" Those are your words.  What I was getting at was something else, which really comes down to `etherscan`'s choice of wording - "Write Contract". Its misleading. Inaccurate. You're not "WRITING" a contract through that Tab. You're not editing it, adding or deleting code from it, you're not "writing" anything.  You're INTERACTING with it. At best, you're writing TO it. So their wording is misleading - and that's why I asked "why is it there?" The Tab should really be called "Interact with Contract" and that would solve it.

Comment: Really, all they're doing here is what `myEtherWallet` has been letting you do through their "Contracts" Tab, which is let you pull up existing contracts and access and run individual functions from those contracts - through a drop-down menu. So in terms of `etherescan`'s choice of wording for this Tab, `Access Contract` would be another good title.

Comment: "Are you actually able to execute all of these functions? Meaning, perform the transferring of Tokens from some person's account to your account for example?" did not imply the understanding you seem to have now. You'll have to ask them about their choice of wording in the UI. You should vote for the answer if you found it informative and accept it if it addressed the original question _as it was written_.

Comment: Rob, in all honestly I do not feel that you answered my question - which is fine, cause you made the effort - several times, and I totally and completely appreciate it. That's what `StackExchange` is all about.  But you can clearly see from the very first response I wrote to you ("I'm still not clear on WHY the "Write Contract" Tab is being made available to us") that I didn't gain any understanding into the matter from what you wrote - which is why I literally had to make that comment and repeat my key question a second time.

Comment: Since then, I already explained that I figured out what it was that was throwing me off: `etherscan`'s poor choice of wording ("Write Contract”), how I find it to be misleading, and how all they’re doing is offering a functionality that is similar to the one “myEtherWallet” offers. 

One can reason that if I understand the latter, I certainly understand the former. 

All of which is to say: I figured it out on my own.

Comment: I am however a good sport, and I really really do appreciate your time and energy - so I will mark yours as the right answer, if only because I think there’s a good chance a future reader will find the writing here quite helpful to them.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

So let me get this straight... I find a wallet that has say 1000 Aave tokens, and I open the "Write Contract" tab on the etherscan page for the Aave contract, scroll down to "Transfer Tokens" menu, enter the address for the aforementioned wallet as the Sender's address and my wallet's address for the Recipient, and then enter an Value as 10, hit "Write", approve the transaction in my web3 wallet, then those tokens should be transferred from the address with the 1000 Aave to my address automatically?? Or are there safeguards to prevent this?? Is the responsibility of assurance this isn't possible left up to the contract itself?? Does the sender not have to approve the transaction??

The way it sounds from comments here, as long as the contract doesn't have a specific measure to stop this (which it could possibly not have), then those tokens would be transferred to my wallet pretty simply....
I would assume if it were this easy then there would be more theft of this kind, right?! There's no way its this simple... right?!

Comment: usually, the contract checks if the transaction sender has approval from the owner of the wallet to send those tokens.

Comment: Hi there. Please don't post questions in the answers section. Please post a new question.